# Что за собой скрывает названия версии пакет composer

Tags: composer, package, version

Возник вопрос с неймингом версий пакетов на который не могу найти ответ, возможно версионость пакетов для каждого индивидуальная и не имеет за собой особенности смысла, а только то что сам разработчик заклал какую ему циферку сменить - первую, вторую или третью, хотя я надеюсь какая-то идея и структура там есть, но найти почему-то не могу, к примеру когда в пакете с версии 1.1.1 добавляется в конце 1.1.{2} то это баг-фикс, новая фича, переделка функционала? Как можно приблизительно понять не читая тоны текста "CHANGE LOG" чтобы сразу понять -"ага, вышла версия 1.1.2, что-то по фиксили пакет нужно обновить" и естественно при поддержке соево приложения верно создавать теги?

P.S. прежде чем натыкать минусов киньте ссылку где можно прочитать как это работает)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/258891/  (Версионирование)  Не то?

Comment: «сам разработчик заклал какую ему циферку сменить» — в целом да. Но вообще считается хорошим тоном соблюдать [семантическое версионирование](https://semver.org/lang/ru/) и некоторые даже соблюдают (но некоторые другие всё равно не соблюдают, так что стоит быть внимательным)

Comment: @andreymal Вы мой герой, просто заголовок по вашей ссылке все возложил на свои места https://i.imgur.com/hH2wmCl.png , спасибо вам большое. Вынесите коммент в ответ - отмечу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ от [andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

> «сам разработчик заклал какую ему циферку сменить» — в целом да. Но вообще считается хорошим тоном соблюдать семантическое версионирование и некоторые даже соблюдают (но некоторые другие всё равно не соблюдают, так что стоит быть внимательным)